# Why is the generating function of this combinatorial problem $\prod \frac {1}{1-set(i)*set(j)}$?

Tags: combinations

Divide the 14 elements {A, B, C, C, C, C, D, D, D, D, E, E, E, E} into 7 groups ([one group all have two elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239670/how-to-use-function-generatingfunction-to-solve-this-combinatorial-problem-ef)), and I want to find out how many kinds of methods there are without repetition.

I already know a mathematical way to solve the problem:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
set=\{a,b,c,d,e\} \\
G=\prod \frac {1}{1-set(i)*set(j)} \\=\frac{1}{\left(1-a^2\right) \left(1-b^2\right)
   \left(1-c^2\right) \left(1-d^2\right) \left(1-e^2\right)
   (1-a b) (1-a c) (1-a d) (1-a e) (1-b c) (1-b d) (1-b e)
   (1-c d) (1-c e) (1-d e)}
\end{array}
$$

Then we expand the generating function g at the point $\{0,0,0,0,0\}$ into a multivariate Taylor series.

Where the index of $a$ is 1, the index of $b$ is 1, the index of $c$ is 4, the index of $d$ is 4, and the index of $e$ is 4, the coefficient of this term `96` is the desired result.

```
set = {a, b, c, d, e};
f = Times @@ 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[Table[1/(1 - set[[i]]*set[[j]]), {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]]]
SeriesCoefficient[f, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 4}, {d, 0, 4}, {e, 
  0, 4}]
```

But I don't understand why its generating function is in this form. I hope you can give a detailed explanation and other related examples.

There may be some grammatical errors in the above problems. Please correct them.

Answer (score 2):

The non-rigorous intuition for what's going is:

Let $S=\{AA,AB,AC,...,DD,DE,EE\}$ be the set of 15 different 2-element groups, and call a multiset of elements of $S$ (such as a particular division of the given 14 elements into 2-element groups) an "arrangement". We can completely describe an arrangement by saying how many of each element of $S$ it has. E.g. $(AC,BC,CC,DD,DD,EE,EE)$ has 0 ABs, 1 AC, 0ACs, ..., 2 DDs, 0 DEs, 2 EEs.

Now imagine expanding the product
$$\left((aa)^0+(aa)^1+(aa)^2+(aa)^3+\dots\right)\left((ab)^0+(ab)^1+(ab)^2+(ab)^3+\dots\right)\cdots\left((ee)^0+(ee)^1+(ee)^2+(ee)^3+\dots\right)$$
by just "multiplying it out" into a big sum. Each term of the result will correspond to choosing exactly one term from each of the 15 factors. This is the same as specifying an *arrangement* by choosing how many of each kind of group it has, and the term we end up with consists of the elements that the corresponding arrangement uses. For example, the arrangement $(AC,AC,BC,DD)$ corresponds to the term $(aa)^0(ab)^0(ac)^2(ad)^0(ae)^0(bb)^0(bc)^1(bd)^0(be)^0\cdots(dd)^1(de)^0(ee)^0=a^2bc^3d^2$.

If we then "combine like terms" of our big sum, we're effectively counting arrangements according to which multiset of underlying elements they use. In particular, the coefficient on $abc^4d^4e^4$ is the number of arrangements that use exactly the 14 elements in question.

The $G$ in your question is exactly the product above, after applying the geometric series formula $x^0+x^1+x^2+\ldots=\frac1{1-x}$ to each factor.